# Sql Server 2000 - table last modified

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know of ANY way to query a Sql Server 2000 database to find out when tables were last modified please?

Comment: Do you mean when the structure / model was change or the data in the table.?

Comment: I meant the data in the table but the general consensus seems to be that is not possible in Sql Server 2000 - thanks for your response anyway

Comment: this is done often but you have to build it yourself -- add last modified columns to the tables and update them at the in SPs, triggers or at the application layer

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately not stored in SQL 2000 unless you have custom columns storing that type of data for the table. So if you are looking for something built into SQL Server you are sadly out of luck.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was just making a last dirch attempt to find out!